# Error installing PyQt5

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to install PyQt 5 on my Mac osx 10.9, so I did the following:

1. I downloaded SIP and installed it.
2. I downloaded QT 5.3.2 and installed it by its installer, so now its installed in

> /Users/username/Qt

so i have added it to the path by doing this

> `PATH=/Users/gollahalli/Qt/5.3/clang_64/bin:$PATH`

and

> `export PATH`

3. Next i tried installing PyQt by doing the following

> python3 configure.py --qmake /Users/username/Desktop/PyQt

but i still get this error

> Error: PyQt5 requires Qt v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v3. Use the --qmake flag to specify the correct version of quake.

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You could point --qmake directly to the binary rather than the toplevel directory. In my case this was:

```
python3 configure.py --qmake ~/Qt5.4.1/5.4/clang_64/bin/qmake
```